# MailKit receive emails doesn't show emails received (Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mailkit

I am using Xamarin android (C#), and have the following code for receiving emails:

```
                using (var client = new Pop3Client())
                {
                    gstrEmailMessages = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                    client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
                    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                    client.Authenticate("xxx@gmail.com", "yyyy");  //actual values not shown here

                    //Fetch emails:
                    for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = client.GetMessage(i);
                        gstrEmailMessages = gstrEmailMessages + "Subject: {0} " + message.Subject + "\n";
                    }

                    //Disconnect connection:
                    client.Disconnect(true);

                    KMsScannedTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.KMsScannedTextView_id);
                    KMsScannedTextView.Text = gstrEmailMessages;
                }
```

I have set up my gmail account to show
Status: POP is enabled for all mail
and
Status: IMAP is disabled
There are 4 emails waiting to be viewed. (When there were 29 emails waiting it caused an error.)
The app compiles and runs just fine, the code above is under a button (at present) and when I tap the button the app runs the code successfully without error - but without showing any emails - and instead shows the correct time (see gstrEmailMessages above) in the textview KMsScannedTextView.
The text view should of course display the result of 'Subject: {0} " + message.Subject + "\n"' four times.
There's another button which simply re-displays gstrEmailMessages in the textview KMsScannedTextView, so I know there's no delay.
What else should I look for to find out why no emails are shown? Is the For loop wrong in some way?

Of course, when it all works I'll set it up in an intent, but this code above is just for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with following and also read links on the page : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: have you actually debugged the code?  Is client.Count the correct (4) value?  Does GetMessage() return a value?  Shouldn't you set your auth value before you call connect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your GMail Settings, go to the **Forwarding and IMAP/POP** tab, and then change your POP settings to

1. **Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)**
2. **When messages are accessed with POP keep Gmail's copy in the Inbox**

Most likely these aren't what your current settings are, so even though it *looks like* you have 4 messages in your Inbox when viewed in the web client, MailKit's Pop3Client sees 0 messages.

Comment: Thank you. It works now, except for the following: it counts a message once only. After that it doesn't see any messages remaining in the inbox. Does it matter that these emails also go to my desktop email program (Thunderbird)? My gmail account is set to Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded) and When messages are accessed with POP keep Gmail's copy in the Inbox. Still only counts a message once.

Comment: Make sure Thunderbird isn't configured to delete messages after downloading via POP (that's the default).

Comment: Thanks again, jstedfast.

Comment: @JonathanT If you solved this issue by this answer, please accept it(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.